# How to filter out the output of Get-AzureRmContext -ListAvailable?

Tags: azure, powershell

I am plying with powershell API for Azure. I would like to filter out the output of `Get-AzureRmContext -ListAvailable` cmdlet, how can I do so?

Say, I want only subscriptions matching some pattern.

I have googled however could not find working solution.

PS the API documentation could be found here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.profile/get-azurermcontext?view=azurermps-6.12.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use built-in powershell functionality:

```
(Get-AzContext -ListAvailable).Subscription | Where-Object { $_.Name -Match 'expression' }
```

ps. I'm using the latest azure powershell cmdlet names so the answer is viable another couple of years from now, you can use "old" style cmdlets (the one in your question)

Comment: thank you. it works. with slight modification from my side though , it is `Subscription | Where-Object { $_.Name -Match 'Pattern' }` rather than `Get-AzContext -ListAvailable ...`